# How to bind a macro inside a lambda in newLISP?

Tags: lisp, newlisp

So I have this function:

```
(define (try try-block catch-block finally-block)
    ; Implements try/catch/finally like in most other languages
    )
```

for which I would like to create a "helper" macro that avoids the need for saying `(lambda () ...)` over and over again, kind of like `set` and `setq`:

```
(define-macro (tryq try-block catch-block finally-block)
    (try
        (lambda () (eval try-block))
        (lambda () (eval catch-block))
        (lambda () (eval finally-block))))
```

However, because `lambda` delays its arguments, the above program doesn't work -- the `try-block` inside `eval` is empty by the time it is evaluated, since it is inside a `lambda`.

How do I go about implementing this functionality *correctly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'expand' will do the job and you may also look into 'letex' which is a combination of 'let' and 'expand'.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found it...

It turns out I need to use [expand](http://www.newlisp.org/downloads/newlisp_manual.html#expand).